# How to find the average value of a discontinuous function

Tags: continuity, average

A car covers $\frac{1}{3}$ distance with speed $20\frac{m}{s}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ with $60\frac{m}{s}$. What is the average speed over the entire interval?

Due to the discontinuity of the function, I am not able to do so, how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, how does the fact that the velocity function is discontinuous give you problems?

Comment: I tried using $\frac { 1 }{ b-a } \int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)dx }$ by separating it in two intervals, that didn't work

Comment: Too fancy. Let the distance be say $300$ metres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Average speed will be total distance/total time

If $3S$ m is the total distance, time for the $1/3$ distance will be $=\dfrac S{20}$ sec

Comment: time for 1/3 distance will be S/20, and time for 2/3 distance would  be 2S/60S, av velocity would be 3S/(S/20+2S/60)=36, Is it correct?

Comment: @Alan, What is more important that the answer is the idea. Have you understood that?

Comment: More or less, Is it correct?

Comment: @Alan, I think so